# Unable to access a database on a DB server from a different remote server

Tags: command-line, powershell, remote-desktop

I am trying to run a script that runs a SQL query. It works fine when executing on the DB server itself, but when I try to run that same script on the remote server it fails. I then tried to save the powershell file on the DB server, and just have the remote server execute that powershell file but it claims the file doesn't exist.

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName "advtch-db1" -ScriptBlock {
 Push-Location C:\Scripts\SQL 
 ls -r
 }
```

The output of this code shows everything BUT the new powershell file I just created.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName advtch-db1 -ScriptBlock {
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "advtch-db1" -Query "
SELECT TOP (1000) [SettingID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Value]
      ,[LastUpdated]
  FROM [advtch_TEST].[dbo].[Settings]
"
}
```

When I run the command thats inside the -ScriptBlock in the DB server it executes just fine. But when I try to run on the remote server it gives the following error.

```
 Database 'advtch_TEST' cannot be opened because it is offline.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
    + PSComputerName        : advtch-db1
```

Comment: Try running with a credential at the end of the last `}` as `-Credential Get-Credential` and when prompted type in the credential and see if that makes any difference. I've most certainly done this before so I know it's possible but try that and see if that makes any difference to start. I have more explicit examples if needed but ping me back and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try and troubleshoot using an interactive session:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "advtch-db1"
[advtch-db1]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "advtch-db1" -Query "My query"
```

The SQL module may not be getting loaded, or maybe there are other issues that may be clearer this way. For reference, here is a command I use for the same purpose:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'MySQLServer.domain.com' {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.\SQLEXPRESS'  -Database MyDB -Query "SELECT strDisplayName,field1,field2,field3 
FROM t_table
WHERE field1 IN (6,7,43,83,94,95,96)
ORDER BY strDisplayName"
} | select strDisplayName,field1,field2,field3
```

You might also try connecting using [sqlcmd.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) from your local machine, though this will only return strings instead of objects. Good enough for reports and things:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S myServer\instanceName
```